# Cannot add a column to an access database through ADONet/ODBC (or OleDb)

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, odbc, ado

I recently put together a script to add a column to a database table as a part of a data conversion process. I'm using ODBC and performance isn't a big concern.

**JScript** - This works fine

```
var cxn = new ActiveXObject("Adodb.connection");
cxn.Open(connectionString);
var statement = "alter table MyTable add MyColumn varchar(40) null";
var changed = 0;
cxn.execute(statement, changed, 0x80);
```

**MFC/C++ & CDatabase/ODBC** - Works also works fine

```
CDatabase db;
if (db.Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, szConnectionString, FALSE)) 
   db.ExecuteSQL("ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn VARCHAR(40) NULL");
```

**C#/ADONet** - Doesn't work

```
using (var cxn = GetOpenConnection())
{
    var cmd = cxn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn VARCHAR(40) NULL";

    // MS Access specific SQL also fails
    //cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyColumn TEXT(40)";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ....
```

ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1 indicating a failure. I'm not sure why.

Again, all three are using ODBC with the same connection string. Why doesn't the C# version work?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this revolves around framework and non-framework objects.

In JScript you are connecting to the access backend using an Adodb connection which is a COM+ (ie not a .Net) object.

I'm not sure exactly what the ODBC connection is but expect that it is similar.

With ADO.Net you are connecting using a managed (.Net) connection, and it fails.

I dont know specifically that the access backend isnt a .Net object (if it is a .mdb it definitely isnt, but I'm less sure about a .accdb), but this is certainly the implication of the results you've reported.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this for the commandtext:

```
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD COLUMN [MyColumn] TEXT(40)";
```